# Cannot Optimize where NSolve and NDSolveValue are involved with Multi-Variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, finite-element-method, variable

My **Objective Function** is `Sqrt[Sum[((sol[[j]])^2), {j, 1, noofnode}]/noofnode]` with variables `v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6`. But just after running the code, I got continuous error messages like `NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.` `Part::partd: Part specification {}[[0,1]] is longer than depth of object.` Finally, I get nothing at the output.

I am new to using Mathematica. As a result, I could not solve my Optimization Problem, and I got stuck at this point for a long time. Please, someone, help me to optimize this problem.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
    FindMinimum[b = 20;
     a = 15;   
     es = 1;                                                 (*Element \
    size for FEA*)
     noofnode = IntegerPart[((b - a)/es) + 1];
     init = 0 &;
     eb = 380*10^9;     (*MPa*)
     ea = 71*10^9;       (*MPa*)
     new = 0.3;                             (*Poisson's Ratio*)           \     
     gama = ea/(3*(1 - 2*new));  (*Bulk Modulus of A*)
     miua = ea/(2*(1 + new));      (*Shear Modulus of A*)
     gamb = eb/(3*(1 - 2*new));    (*Bulk Modulus of B*)
     miub = eb/(2*(1 + new));         (*Shear Modulus of B*)
     alpha = 23.1*10^(-6);
     row = 2.70;
     Y = (miu*(9*gam + 8*miu))/(6*gam + 12*miu);
     ta = 20;                      (*Degree C*)
     tb = 100;   
     rpm = 150.0;
     wom = (2.0*\[Pi]*rpm)/60;
     kb = 35.0;
     ka = 204.0;
     lam = (1/(b - a))*
       Log[kb/ka];               (*Constant for Exponential Temp Profile*)
     f[ri_] := ExpIntegralEi[-lam*ri];
     c1 = (tb - ta)/(f[b] - f[a]);
     c2 = ((ta*f[b]) - (tb*f[a]))/(f[b] - f[a]);
     T[r_] := c2 + c1*ExpIntegralEi[-lam*r];
     Va = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};     
     ed = Array[
       init, {noofnode, 
        1}];                                    (*Modulus of Elasticity*) \             
     For[ex = 1, ex < noofnode + 1, ex++,
      x = Values[
        NSolve[Va[[
              ex]]*((gama - gam)/(3*gama + 4*miu)) + (1 - 
               Va[[ex]])*((gamb - gam)/(3*gamb + 4*miu)) == 0 &&
          Va[[
              ex]]*((miua - miu)/(miua + Y)) + (1 - 
               Va[[ex]])*((miub - miu)/(miub + Y)) == 0, {gam, miu}, 
         Reals]];
      x2 = Dimensions[x];
      gam = x[[x2[[1]], 1]];
      miu = x[[x2[[1]], 2]];
      ed[[ex]] = (9*gam*miu)/(3*gam + miu);
      Clear[gam, miu];
      ];
     e = Interpolation[ed];
     z = NDSolveValue[{(-F[r] + 
          r (F'[r] + 
             r ((3 + new) r row wom^2 + alpha e [r - 14] T[r] + 
                F''[r])))/(e [r - 14] r) == 0, F[a] == 0, F[b] == 0}, 
       F, {r, a, b}];
     sol = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];          
     y = 0;
     For[i = a, i < b + 1, i++,
      y = y + 1;
      sol[[y]] = (z[i]*10^(-9))/i;
      ];
     {Sqrt[Sum[((sol[[j]])^2), {j, 1, noofnode}]/noofnode], 0 < v1 < 1, 
      0 < v2 < 1, 0 < v3 < 1, 0 < v4 < 1, 0 < v5 < 1, 0 < v6 < 1}, {v1, 
      v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}]
```

Comment: There is a backslash just before gama and also after "(*Modulus of Elasticity*)\  "  Further, "NSolve" returns an empty list what make the following code to fail.

Comment: I think backslash doesn’t create any problem. That came when I copied the code from Mathematica to the Google Chrome. Can you please help me with the solution to the code failure?

Comment: Bakslashes will prevent the code from running. Then in the argument to NSolve, there is a undefined variable "v1" (or "v2".. depending on ex), that prevents the evaluation of "NSolve". If you need a symbolic solution, use "Solve"

Comment: v1,v2,…. are the variables for FindMinimum. These are the variables for optimizing the problem. If I define these variables, how can I optimize? My main goal is to optimize the problem.